# open and write statements in Fortran

Tags: file-io, fortran

I am working through the Fortran tutorial at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran/Fortran_simple_input_and_output.  In the following program, what does unit=out_unit do?

```
program xproduct
  implicit none
  integer            :: i,j
  integer, parameter :: out_unit=20

  print*,"enter two integers"
  read (*,*) i,j

  open (unit=out_unit,file="results.txt",action="write",status="replace")
  write (out_unit,*) "The product of",i," and",j
  write (out_unit,*) "is",i*j

  close (out_unit)
end program xproduct
```

When I run this program, the text file results.txt contains the following text:

```
 The product of           2  and           3
 is           6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It specifies the "terminal" to write to.  The number contained in out_unit represents the file you opened with the `open` statement.  If you hadn't used the `open` statement and specified the file, output would have been to `fort.20`

Some terminal numbers have specific meanings. For example, 6 is (usually) stdout, and 5 is (usually) stdin.

Answer (score 4):

> In the following program, what does `unit=out_unit` do?

It's using [named function parameters](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Named_parameters#Fortran).

---

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter):

> Named parameters or keyword arguments refer to a computer language's support for function calls that clearly state the name of each parameter within the function call itself.
>
> A function call using named parameters differs from a regular function call in that the values are passed by associating each one with a parameter name, instead of providing an ordered list of values.

Comment: Hm, based on @Dan's answer I might have _completely_ misinterpreted the question.

Comment: I think you're both right, you just answered different parts of the underlying question... +1s all around.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure that *I'm* the one who misinterpreted the question. Then people upvoted my answer, so I figured it must still be useful and didn't delete it.

Comment: Both answers are very helpful to me!  Since you helped me earlier today, I have learned that in Fortran the terminals are numbered.  From what I read here [link](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~hile/fortran/fort7.htm), you can number the files/terminals with any number that you want, except 6, which the GNU Fortran compiler reserves to refer to the screen.

Comment: @Andrew: to stay on the safe side, it is often advised to don't use any unit numbers below 10. It isn't specified in the standard, but most compilers use some of those low numbers for things like stdin, stdout, and other preconnected 'devices'.

Comment: @eriktous: OK, thank you very much!  I will definitely use units above 10 in the future.

Comment: This is, actually, not correct; OPEN is a statement, not a procedure call.

Comment: @Matt: That OPEN is not a procedure, and thus whatever rules there might or might not be for named procedure arguments don't apply. For the OPEN syntax, see e.g. R904 in F2008.